# Cloud function 2gen failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-functions

When running my code i receive the following error:
Ready condition status changed to False for Service function with message: Revision is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.

The function makes 1300 api requests to mercadolibre. The logs shows the response is ok but it throws the message before finishing all the requests.

I set the cf with 1 gb of memory and the max timeout.

Is it possible to use a cf to execute this kind of code or should I use another google product? In that case which one do you recommend?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. I would like to know what does this error mean?: failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable